# Python how to paste clipboard not in terminal

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to paste in my OS in Python (not only the terminal).

This is my code to test but it only pastes in stdout.

```
import pyperclip
from time import sleep

pyperclip.copy('this is the text\nok\n')
n = 0
while n < 10:
    n += 1
    sleep(1)
    pyperclip.paste()
```

I know it should only paste in terminal, but I did not find any way to let Python paste in another application.

In my test (not real env), I use Notepadd and VSCode, and I see I can manually `ctrl+v` and clipboard works fine, but it does not automatically paste.

Comment: Are you running this code in IDLE? Because according to the [documentation](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), `call pyperclip.paste() and the text will be returned as a string value`. It shouldn't be actually pasting the text anywhere, for me nothing shows up in a terminal because there's no `print()`.

Comment: @shriakhilc yes. If I use `print(pyperclip.paste())`, it prints the texts. But my issue is python cannot automatically paste in another opened tab or program, like Notepad.

Comment: @shriakhilc, thanks. Yes it answers me. I just saw `pyautogui` and was reading its docs.

Comment: `pyperclip` is NOT for pasting to another program - only to paste from your code to clipboard and get from clipboard to your code. And if you see it in console then it has nothing to do with pasting - you simply get from clipboard and display/print it - and `print()` send it to console/terminal.